# Laravel Lumen - handle invalid route

Tags: php, laravel, routes, lumen

In Lumen, how can I handle invalid routes (URLs)?

Lumen's [documentation](https://lumen.laravel.com/docs/5.1/routing#throwing-404-errors) says to put `abort(404);` but I'm not where to put this.

If I put it in my route file, it gives me this error

```
Fatal error: Call to a member function send() on string in C:\....\vendor\laravel\lumen-framework\src\Application.php on line 408
```

This is the code where the error is thrown:

```
protected function handleUncaughtException($e)
{
    $handler = $this->make('Illuminate\Contracts\Debug\ExceptionHandler');

    if ($e instanceof Error) {
        $e = new FatalThrowableError($e);
    }

    $handler->report($e);

    if ($this->runningInConsole()) {
        $handler->renderForConsole(new ConsoleOutput, $e);
    } else {
        $handler->render($this->make('request'), $e)->send(); <---line 408
    }
}
```

This is the stuff in my route file (just added one route):

```
$app->group(['middleware' => 'stratus_auth', 'namespace' => 'App\Http\Controllers'], function ($app) {

     $app->get('/login', ['as' => 'login', 'middleware' => 'user_logged', 'uses' => 'LoginController@index']);
     ...
     ...
     ...
     $app->abort(404);
});
```

I suspect I'm not adding the abort command properly in the route file.

Ideally if the route isn't valid I want it to redirect to `/ask` URL.

Any help is appreciated. And please let me if any more info or code is needed. I'll add it to the question.

**-----EDIT:-----**

Without the abort() I get this error with an invalid URL:

```
exception 'Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Exception\NotFoundHttpException' in C:\Empire\LifeLearn\Repos\lifelearn_sofie_application\vendor\laravel\lumen-framework\src\Application.php:1264
```

This is line 1264 from the Application.php

```
protected function handleDispatcherResponse($routeInfo)
{
    switch ($routeInfo[0]) {
        case Dispatcher::NOT_FOUND:
            throw new NotFoundHttpException;    <---ln 1264

        case Dispatcher::METHOD_NOT_ALLOWED:
            throw new MethodNotAllowedHttpException($routeInfo[1]);

        case Dispatcher::FOUND:
            return $this->handleFoundRoute($routeInfo);
    }
}
```

As per the lumen documentation, this is the second way to handle an error which is what it seems to be doing.

> Secondly, you may manually throw an instance of  Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Exception\NotFoundHttpException.

But how can I show a 404 page instead of the error on the page?

Comment: It'll be able to if you fix the error. Show the code surrounding the line in question.

Comment: Do you want to see the code in the application file? Posted it in the question

Comment: You must be passing the wrong thing to it in your routes. What do your routes look like?

Comment: Added a snapshot of the route file. Maybe I'm putting the abort() line in the wrong place?

Comment: Yep it needs to be inside a route block. I can't find any documentation for it at the moment. From memory it's something like `$app->get('*', function () { $app->abort(404); }); ` as the last route in the file.

Comment: Added some more info. Looks like right now invalid URLs are being handled though Symfony.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I got this to work with the help of these links:

- [how-do-i-create-a-custom-404-error-page](https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/general-discussion/how-do-i-create-a-custom-404-error-page)
- [create-custom-error-pages-in-laravel-5](http://www.techigniter.in/blogs/tutorials/create-custom-error-pages-in-laravel-5/)

Mainly the first one. Bestmomo's answers did the trick. The second link is useful if you want to handle different kinds of errors 404, 500 etc.

I didn't have to add anything to my route file.
Just had to change the app/Exceptions/Handler.php file as described in the answer. I will more detail here soon.

Make sure to add `use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Exception\NotFoundHttpException;` in your Handler.php